# Mantle - Mapping Nested Data Structure

Tags: ios, json

I have a slightly complex nested JSON object that I need to map to Objective-C class. One think I need to do is skip levels in JSON when mapping. Here is what I mean:

I want to map the following JSON Dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = @{
         @"status" : @"PASSWORD_EXPIRED",
         @"_embedded" : @{
                 @"user" : @{
                         @"id" : @"00ub0oNGTSWTBKOLGLNR",
                         @"profile" : @{
                                 @"login" : @"isaac@example.org",
                                 @"firstName" : @"Isaac",
                                 @"lastName" : @"Brock",
                                 @"locale" : @"en_US",
                                 @"timeZone" : @"America/Los_Angeles"
                                 }
                         }
                 }
         };
```

to

```
@interface Authentication : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate* expiresAt;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* status;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* relayState;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* sessionToken;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* stateToken;

//Embeded Resources
@property (strong, nonatomic) User* user;
@end
```

As you can see I am not creating an object for "_embeded". I am skipping it and mapping user to a User object.

Can this be achieved? If so How?

I have tried this in the implementation but it did not work:

```
@implementation Authentication
+ (NSDictionary*)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
    return @{
             @"expiresAt" : @"expiresAt",
             @"status" : @"status",
             @"sessionToken" : @"sessionToken",
             @"stateToken" : @"stateToken",
             @"relayState" : @"relayState",
             @"user" : @"_embeded/user",
             };
}

+ (NSValueTransformer *)userJSONTransformer {
    return [NSValueTransformer mtl_JSONDictionaryTransformerWithModelClass:User.class];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to do it with the following code:

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)userJSONTransformer {
    return [MTLValueTransformer reversibleTransformerWithForwardBlock:^id(NSDictionary *userDict) {
        return [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[User class] fromJSONDictionary:userDict error:nil];
    } reverseBlock:^id(User *user) {
        return [MTLJSONAdapter JSONDictionaryFromModel:user];
    }];
}
```

And also in `+JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey` I think it should be `@"user" : @"_embeded.user"`

Comment: See `-[MTLJSONAdapter transformerForModelPropertiesOfClass:]` also.